# Image View moves after image changes(after pressing it)

Tags: java, android, image, imageview, android-imageview

ok so i'm currently learning android and i am trying to make a memory app where you have to find 2 matching pictures.

I have almost finished it but there is one problem that is bugging me, i looked it up and someone else had the same problem but the only answer he got was to make the image button a fixed dp size, but i don't think that's a solution if you are making an app for a variety of different android devices.

I made the images image views and they are all the same image but every time someone presses one of the image views it changes to a certain image that is fixed for that spot for that round.

The problem is every time an image is pressed the whole layout moves slightly but enough to be noticed and get annoyed by it, how can i fix this without giving them a fixed dp size.

Thanks :).

i made it with table layout inside a linear layout, this is one of the rows.

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp" />

    </TableRow>
```

Comment: Since you're mentioning another question (and answer), it might be helpful to include a link to that question.

Comment: If you draw some selection background when image is pressed perhaps it may be caused by custom paddings/margins used for that selection background.